# Find the line which passing thorugh point $(9,-13,0)$ and is parallel to the intersection line of planes $-5x-5y-z=0,-5x+5y+z=0$.

Tags: solution-verification, analytic-geometry

Find the line which passing thorugh point $(9,-13,0)$ and is parallel to the intersection line of planes $-5x-5y-z=0,-5x+5y+z=3$.

My attempt :

Find the intersection line :

det$\begin{pmatrix}
i&j&k\\
-5&-5&-1\\
-5&5&1\\
\end{pmatrix}=10\hat{j}-50\hat{k}.$

Denote $z=0 \implies -5x-5y=0,-5x+5y=3 \implies x=-\frac{3}{10},y=\frac{3}{10}$

The intersection line is : $\vec{r(t)}=(-\frac{3}{10},\frac{3}{10},0)+t(0,10,-50)$

Is the requested line is $\vec{r(t)}=(9,-13,0)+t(0,10,-50)$ ?

Comment: Sorry , I fixed the equations

Comment: Yes the method is ok.